# What is the operation of Object.assign when it is not assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have the following Model

```
Driver {
  public id: string;
  public name: string;
  public surname: string;
  public asset?: Asset;
  public assetId?: string;
  public phoneNumber: string;
  public companyId: string;
}
```

Additionally, I have 2 elements of the Driver type called:
*sourceDriver* & *driver*

```
if (this.sourceDriver) {
   Object.assign(this.sourceDriver, driver);
   this.sourceDriver = null;
} else {
  this.dataSource.data.push(driver);
}
this.refresh()
```

What is the function of **Object.assign** when placing 2 parameters and not assigning it to a variable?

### More Information

Use Angular 6, components of Angular Material (MatDialog MatTable), and this portion of code belongs to an edition/creation

Comment:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @deceze Can't you close as off-topic (looking for an off-site ressource)?

Comment: @Bergi OP is not really *asking* for an off-site resource, but for an explanation. Which is fine IMO, it's just badly researched and could have been answered by reading the documentation and/or experimenting…

Comment: @deceze OK, maybe it's just me trying to abuse close reasons where downvotes would be more appropriate... Yeah, guess you're right.

Comment: In the documentation does not mention or does not have examples about launching the Object.assign function without assigning it to a variable

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.assign(this.sourceDriver, driver);
```

This assigns all properties and their values *from* `driver` *to* `this.sourceDriver`. This updated `this.sourceDriver` object is then also returned, but that is pretty irrelevant here and `Object.assign` has an effect on `this.sourceDriver` even if you ignore the return value.

Since you're setting `this.sourceDriver` to `null` in the next line, this whole operation is pretty pointless though.

Comment: I understand the operation of the Object.assign function, if we place it as var a = Object.assign (b, c); However, I do not understand what happens if I have:
Object.assign (b, c) and subsequently
b = null.

The problem is that if I remove the line of code: Object.assign or equality to null everything stops working.

Comment: Well, I don't know what stops working or why, but I have explained what `Object.assign` does. Have you understood that, or do you have some other question about my explanation?